# Русские символы в URL

Tags: php, кодировка, url

Здравствуйте.
Как можно передать строку, содержащую русский текст через GET-запрос скрипту, чтобы русские символы не превращались в кракозябры? В GH, Opera и MF все работает, а вот в IE как всегда - нет. Если не сложно, то приведите маленький примерчик. Спасибо.

**Передаю GET-запрос так:**

```
$a=$_SESSION["login"]; echo urlencode(iconv("CP1251","UTF-8",$a))
```

**Обрабатываю GET-запрос примерно так:**

```
echo iconv("CP1251","UTF-8",$_GET["id"]) ;
    mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
    $a = urldecode($_GET["id"]);
    echo " --> ".iconv("UTF-8","UTF-8",$a) ;
    $log = strip_tags(trim(mb_strtolower($_GET["id"])));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$a = $_GET["id"];
if (!preg_match('//u', $a)) {
    $a = iconv("cp1251","UTF-8",$a);
}
echo $a;
```

Comment: А urlencode() надо использовать при создании Get-запроса?

Comment: @Deonis, все работает! Не могу поверить! Спасибо большое! А как так получилось?

Comment: Если этот код решает вашу проблему, значит у вас ошибка описании проблемы.

Comment: @Deonis, вы меня вечно выручаете с этими кодировками...

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.urlencode.php)

test.php

```
<a href="./test2.php?id=<?php echo urldecode('Всем привет')?>">Привет</a>
```

test2.php

```
<?php
    var_dump($_GET);
```

Comment: Да, это можно считать очевидным, но хотелось бы увидеть пример, если можно =)

Comment: В IE это не работает. Квадраты вместо букв...

Comment: зачем при передаче переводите из cp1251 в utf8, и при получении опять ? достаточно:
    $url = 'http:// ...?param=' . urlencode('русский текст');

при получении: var_dump($_GET['param']);

Comment: В IE это тоже не работает...почему?

Comment: Выставите кодировку utf-8 в браузере :)

Comment: Этот код у вас работает ?
test.php
<pre>
<a href="./test2.php?id=<?php echo urldecode('Всем привет')?>">Привет</a>
</pre>
test2.php
<pre>
<?php
var_dump($_GET);
</pre>